# \label inside an align environment

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

It seems like whenever I use `\label{an-label}` inside the align environment, and then use to refer to it using `\refeq{an-label}`, I get the section number instead of the equation number.
This does not happen when I use the equation environment.

For example:

```
\begin{align}
f(x) & = x^2 \label{label1}
\end{align}

Equation \refeq{label1}
```

would display the section number instead of the equation number.
I use mathtools. Is there any reason for this to happen?

When looking in google, it is stated in some web page that `\begin{align} \end{align}` should be used with the `\label{}` to name an equation, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please provide a minimum example. I cannot reproduce your problem on TeX-Live 2010.

Comment: what Willie said - please provide a MWE. I cannot reproduce your problem in MiKTeX 2.8 or MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: The problem might be with `\refeq` try using `\ref` or `\eqref` instead.

Comment: I object to this being closed.  I had the same problem and was able to resolve it by looking at an answer here.  If the question is only relevant to a few people, how about if everyone else just doesn't read it?  Isn't that how you normally operate if a question isn't relevant to you?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're using the `align` environment for a single equation instead of the `equation` environment. Anyway, I've tried this code and it works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\label{sec1}
 This is section \ref{sec1}.
 \section{Section 2}
 \label{sec2}
 This is section \ref{sec2}
 \begin{equation}
 2+2=4
 \end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 3+3=6
 \end{equation}
 \begin{align}
 f(x)&=x^2 \label{ali1}
 \end{align}
 Take a look at equation \eqref{ali1}.
\end{document}
```

I've tried using the "mathtools" package instead of "amsmath" but I didn't found any problem... 
I don't realize what is really happening...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues like Stefan, however with "gather".
Since I found the answer to his issue and also could reproduce the "wrong" referencing, I would like to share my findings with you.

It depends where you put the `\label` in your equation environment.
Working example: In this example, you get the correct label for the one label that you assign to the equations.

```
\begin{gather}
\arraycolsep=3pt
\medmuskip = 1mu
{^{O}{\dot{\psi}(t)}} = \int^{t}_{0} \frac{{^{O}\V{\tau}_{G,z}}}{{^{B}{J}_{zz}}} dt + {^{O}{\dot{\psi}(t=0)}}, \nonumber \\
{^{O}{\psi(t)}} = \int^{t}_{0} (\int^{t}_{0} \frac{{^{O}\V{\tau}_{G,z}}}{{^{B}{J}_{zz}}} dt + {^{O}{\dot{\psi}(t=0)}}) dt \nonumber \\
\label{calcAngularPosVel} + {^{O}{\psi}(t=0)}, \\
{^{O}{\dot{\psi}(t)}} = {^{B}{\dot{\psi}(t)}}, {^{O}{\psi(t)}} = {^{B}{\psi(t)}}. \nonumber 
\end{gather}
\ref{calcAngularPosVel}
```

Example with "wrong" reference: In this example, you would get the labeling of the section, not for the equation, since the label tries to reference the last line of all equations provided in the `gather` environment. Hovewer, the last equation line does not provide a label, since the `\nonumber` command suppresses this. Thus, latex cannot reference to this equation.

```
\begin{gather}
\arraycolsep=3pt
\medmuskip = 1mu
{^{O}{\dot{\psi}(t)}} = \int^{t}_{0} \frac{{^{O}\V{\tau}_{G,z}}}{{^{B}{J}_{zz}}} dt + {^{O}{\dot{\psi}(t=0)}}, \nonumber \\
{^{O}{\psi(t)}} = \int^{t}_{0} (\int^{t}_{0} \frac{{^{O}\V{\tau}_{G,z}}}{{^{B}{J}_{zz}}} dt + {^{O}{\dot{\psi}(t=0)}}) dt \nonumber \\
+ {^{O}{\psi}(t=0)}, \\
{^{O}{\dot{\psi}(t)}} = {^{B}{\dot{\psi}(t)}}, {^{O}{\psi(t)}} = {^{B}{\psi(t)}}. \nonumber
\label{calcAngularPosVel}  
\end{gather}
\ref{calcAngularPosVel}
```

So it depends where you put the `\label` command if you want to reference the entire system of equations with only one reference.

Hope this is of help for anyone.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, as the OP is using some `\refeq` command (perhaps from `easyeqn`) and no `\nonumber` command, as you do. You should better open a new question and provide a self-answer, if you think others may profit from it, as this one has been closed for a reason.

Comment: I had the same issue, and this does resolve it: moving the label to within the environment.  Apparently it doesn't matter if it's done with \nolabel as above, or with \align with \notag at the end of lines you don't want labeled.  Though in the question he already does show the label as within the environment, so it's strange that it still wouldn't work.